# Remove empty value(s) from arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, jsoup, baseadapter

I parse all TD elements of a webpage.
There is 1 TD element which seems to be empty.

```
EUR 1,00
EUR 2,00
empty  <--
EUR 3,00
```

How can i fix this and remove the empty item from arraylist (results)?

Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
 try {

          Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpo);  
       // Get all td's 
          Elements waardes = doc.select("TBODY"); 
          Iterator<Element> postIt = waardes.select("td").iterator();
       // Iterator over those elements      
          //ListIterator<Element> postIt = waardes.listIterator(); 
          postIt.next();
          postIt.next();
          postIt.next();
          postIt.next();

          SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
          //SearchResults sr2 = new SearchResults();

          while (postIt.hasNext()) { 

                sr1 = new SearchResults();
                // Add the game text to the ArrayList      
                sr1.setNaam(postIt.next().text()); 
                sr1.setWaarde(postIt.next().text());  
                results.add(sr1); 
          } 

          } catch (Exception e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
          } 

          return results;

        }
```

Edit:
I got it to work like:

```
while (postIt.hasNext()) {  

    String naam = postIt.next().text();
    String waarde = postIt.next().text();

    sr1 = new SearchResults();

    // Add the text to the ArrayList     
    if (!naam.trim().isEmpty() && !waarde.trim().isEmpty()) {
       sr1.setNaam(naam);
       sr1.setWaarde(waarde);
       results.add(sr1); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that you already don't add the `SearchResults` when the `waarde` is empty. This way you don't need to fiddle afterwards with cleaning the one and other.

So, replace

```
sr1.setWaarde(postIt.next().text());  
results.add(sr1);
```

by for example

```
String waarde = postIt.next().text();

if (!waarde.trim().isEmpty()) {
    sr1.setWaarde(waarde);  
    results.add(sr1);
}
```